# Magento 2 add new custom option text field

Tags: magento2

I would like to add new custom option text field like '**New Text Field Title**' in the magento 2.x 'Customizable Options' section could you please suggest me and guide me how to add please refer my screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I got this plugin working properly and saving, etc. I have also created a plugin which allows me to override Select.php. That said, Can someone tell me how to display the new custom options field in Select.php? I need my custom option titles/labels to look like this: <label class="label" for="select_4567" class="my_custom_options_text"> <span>My Custom Options Title</span> </label>

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155680)

Comment: is there any complete answer of this question? I want to implement same in Magento 2.3.4.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a plugin for that. Try following way:

**SR/StackExchange/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions">
        <plugin name="sr_stackexchange_custom_option" type="SR\StackExchange\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**SR/StackExchange/Plugin/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomOptions.php**

```
namespace SR\StackExchange\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;


class CustomOptions
{

    public function afterModifyMeta(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions $subject,
        $meta
    ) {
        $meta['custom_options']['children']['options']['children']['record']['children']['container_option']['children']['container_common']['children']['custom_text'] =
        $this->getTitleFieldConfig(
            200,
            [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Custom Text'),
                            'component' => 'Magento_Catalog/component/static-type-input',
                            'valueUpdate' => 'input',
                            'imports' => [
                                'optionId' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.option_id'
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * Get config for "Title" fields
     *
     * @param int $sortOrder
     * @param array $options
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getTitleFieldConfig($sortOrder, array $options = [])
    {
        return array_replace_recursive(
            [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Custom Text'),
                            'componentType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field::NAME,
                            'formElement' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'custom_text',
                            'dataType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text::NAME,
                            'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                            'validation' => [
                                'required-entry' => false
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            $options
        );
    }
}
```

Clear Magento cache.

**NB: This solution only for M2.1.x. and greater.**

**[Update]**

How to save?

-> create a column 'catalog_product_option' table same as field name. e.g: custom_text

-> clear cache.

Comment: Thanks its showing in the admin side custom options section now but the value unable to save whether we have to do anything ?

Comment: Check here -> https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Initialization/Helper.php#L193

Comment: we followed the link but we were unable to save the value whether we have to do any database changes? could you plz explain in detail thanks

Comment: Check last update code.

Comment: `catalog_product_option` table has no bundle options .

Comment: may be we have to create column into `catalog_product_bundle_option`, Am I right?

Comment: I have create custom field for bundle options, Save successfully into `catelog_product_bundle_options`  table but not loading it after save while edit product. any idea?

Comment: How can i add textarea / Wysiwyg instead of the text field. Is it posible?

Comment: Guys, is there any way to create this new field beside the custom option value' Sku Field ?

Comment: How to use textarea instead of input ?

Comment: Thanks @SohelRana

Comment: @SohelRana  How to add such custom field for bundle options ?

Comment: For simple product, we need to create a column in "catalog_product_option_type_value" table also.

Comment: Hi, @Camit1dk, you got solution for new field next to sku ?

Comment: @ManishaVasani Yes we have done that thing.

Comment: @ Camit1dk Can you please explain, because when I set $sortOrder value, it showing either first or last.

Comment: @Camit1dk - Can you please help me to achieve the same? I want to add custom field beside SKU/Price. Would appreciate your help

Comment: I want to create custom field besides SKU ? is there any idea how to I'll do this? @AhsanHorani have you done this ?