# magento 2.1 product custom option extra field like Quantity?

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-options

I want to add custom field for **quantity** in custom option value like given in image.
I tried following [Magento 2 add new custom option text field](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155132/magento-2-add-new-custom-option-text-field) but it add earlier while i need it with custom option value.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: hi @rajibit singh whether you need this QTY field only to radio button input type (or) for all input types?

Answer (score 6):

**Please follow below steps:**

**Step1:** 
First of all keep back up "**CustomOptions.php**" from the below mentioned path

**i.e** 
`Magento2Root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomOptions.php`

**Step 2:** 
Please follow the below github link and download the file and place the same in the respected (mentioned) path. [Click Here Github Link](https://github.com/NagarajuKasa/demo/blob/master/CustomOptions.php)

**Step 3:** 
Please create a database column in the name of '**qty_option**' for the below 2 tables

**catalog_product_option**

**catalog_product_option_type_value**

[image]

**Step 4:** Clear cache and page_cache and re login into admin and check the same.

**Note:** Once it works using **meld** tool identify the changes what i did in the CustomOptions.php

Using plugin concept try to achieve the same from your end. Thanks

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks, but i need a little bit more on it. example A product default price is 10, 
first custom options price is 2, second custom options price is 3 if I add one quantity to cart the subtotal is (10+2+3)*1 = 15
But if I add two or more quantity it should work as like instead of the default, so the final price should be (10*2)+2+3=>25
always the custom options should add only one time to the default price

Comment: Hello @Nagaraju .. I have followed the steps. I see Qty box in admin but the value doesn't get saved..

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still struggling with that, then you can follow this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/220754/21432

This helped me to resolve my problem. And hope this helps anyone else too!

This explains how you can add a new field with option line item within a bundle.