# Magento2 add new field in bundle item (in option selection)

Tags: magento2, bundle-product

i'am new with magento!

I want to add an image-upload-field to a bundle-product in Magento2. I need this field in the selection-items of the options of the bundle items (see the following image for better understanding):

[image]

Adding a field in the database via my own module was no problem. Now I need to add the field in the adminhtml-template and the selection-model but I don't know how. I tried to change the original files of Magento to check whether I have found the correct files to change/overwrite with my own module but the changes have no effect. I think I need to change this files:

- \vendor\magento\module-bundle\view\adminhtml\templates\product\edit\bundle\option\selection.phtml
- \vendor\magento\module-bundle\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Bundle\Option\Selection.php

I don't know why my changes doesn't affect the output-form (I added something like "abc" in the phtml-template, cleared the whole magento-cache and also the browser-cache). I thought I can extend the template like in this post (but changing the selection-files instead of the option-files): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097689/magento-add-another-new-field-in-bundle-item

What am I doing wrong? Do I edit the wrong files?

**[edit]**

Ok, now i have get the field inside the BundlePanel. The files above were the wrong place to add this field. Ok fine. The right place is:

**\Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel.php**

Via Plugin in my own new module, i have added some new field "custom_text".

Me\HelloWorld\etc\di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel">
        <plugin name="bundle_panel_newfield" type="Me\HelloWorld\Plugin\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Me\HelloWorld\Plugin\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel.php

```
<?php
namespace Me\HelloWorld\Plugin\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form;

class BundlePanel
{
    public function afterModifyMeta(
        \Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel $subject,
        $meta
    ) { 
        $meta['bundle-items']['children']['bundle_options']['children']['record']['children']['product_bundle_container']['children']['bundle_selections']['children']['record']['children']['custom_text'] = $this->getSelectionCustomText();

        return $meta;
    }

     /**
     * Get selection custom field structure
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getSelectionCustomText()
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Form\Field::NAME,
                        'dataType' => Form\Element\DataType\Text::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Form\Element\Input::NAME,
                        'label' => __('Custom Text'),
                        'dataScope' => 'custom_text',
                        'sortOrder' => 120,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

With the meta array i define and order the new field in the panel.

**But now i have two new problems:**

*First Problem:*
You can see in the image below that the plugin places the field correct before my basket image, but not the tableheader. For the th element the option **sortOrder** will be ignored and so the wrong columns are attached to the wrong titles. Why? Bug?

[image]

*Second Problem:*
After saving *(database contains matching column "custom_text" in table "catalog_product_bundle_selection")* the input value will not processed to the database and some manually database value will not appear in the BundlePanel. What is missing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170624/magento-2-1-product-custom-option-extra-field-like-quantity

Comment: Thanks, but it's not clear how it could help me.

Comment: I want to store my data in the "catalog_product_bundle_selection" table, because i need this value to cusomize each added simple product in my bundleproduct.

The other questions goes around adding some extra field in the base option data. This is some other structure. Some structure i found in your post, i don't find in the magento-bundle module.

The field custom_text is added correctly via plugin code above, but the save will not work. Do i have to modify some data models?

Answer (score 9):

Here is my solution:

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundleCustomOptions">
        <plugin
            sortOrder="100"
            name="MyVendorMyModuleBundleModifierCustomOptions"
            type="MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundleCustomOptions"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite">
        <plugin
            sortOrder="100"
            name="MyVendorMyModuleModifierComposite"
            type="MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite"/>
    </type>
    <preference for="Magento\Bundle\Model\LinkManagement" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Preference\Model\LinkManagement" />
</config>
```

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Plugin/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Composite.php

```
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite as BundleComposite;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel;
use Magento\Bundle\Model\Selection;

class Composite
{

    // ...

    protected $locator;
    protected $selection;

    /**
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     * @param Selection $selection
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        Selection $selection
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->selection = $selection;
    }

    public function afterModifyData(BundleComposite $subject, array $data)
    {
        $product = $this->locator->getProduct();
        $modelId = $product->getId();
        $isBundleProduct = $product->getTypeId() === Type::TYPE_CODE;
        if ($isBundleProduct && $modelId) {
            foreach ($data[$modelId][BundlePanel::CODE_BUNDLE_OPTIONS][BundlePanel::CODE_BUNDLE_OPTIONS] as &$option) {
                foreach ($option['bundle_selections'] as &$selection) {
                    $this->selection->load($selection['selection_id']);
                    $selection['custom_field'] = $this->selection->getCustomField();
                }
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }

    // ...

}
```

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Plugin/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/BundleCustomOptions.php

```
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundleCustomOptions as MagentoBundleCustomOptions;

class BundleCustomOptions
{

    // ...

    const FIELD_CUSTOM_FIELD_OPTION_NAME = 'custom_field';

    public function afterModifyMeta(MagentoBundleCustomOptions $subject, array $meta)
    {
        if (isset($meta['bundle-items']['children']['bundle_options']['children']['record']['children']['product_bundle_container']['children']['bundle_selections']['children']['record']['children'])) {


            $meta['bundle-items']['children']['bundle_options']['children']['record']['children']['product_bundle_container']['children']['bundle_selections']['children']['record']['children'][static::FIELD_CUSTOM_FIELD_OPTION_NAME] = $this->getCuststomFieldOptionFieldConfig(125);


            // Reorder table headings

            $action_delete = $meta['bundle-items']['children']['bundle_options']['children']['record']['children']['product_bundle_container']['children']['bundle_selections']['children']['record']['children']['action_delete'];
            unset($meta['bundle-items']['children']['bundle_options']['children']['record']['children']['product_bundle_container']['children']['bundle_selections']['children']['record']['children']['action_delete']);
            $meta['bundle-items']['children']['bundle_options']['children']['record']['children']['product_bundle_container']['children']['bundle_selections']['children']['record']['children']['action_delete'] = $action_delete;

            // There should be more convenient way to reorder table headings

        }

        return $meta;
    }

    protected function getCuststomFieldOptionFieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Custom field'),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Select::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => static::FIELD_CUSTOM_FIELD_OPTION_NAME,
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'default' => 'default',
                        'options' => [
                            [
                                'label' => __('Option 1'),
                                'value' => 'option_1',
                            ],
                            [
                                'label' => __('Option 2'),
                                'value' => 'option_2',
                            ],
                            [
                                'label' => __('Option 3'),
                                'value' => 'option_3',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    // ...

}
```

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Preference/Model/LinkManagement

```
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Preference\Model;

class LinkManagement extends \Magento\Bundle\Model\LinkManagement
{

    // ....

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Bundle\Model\Selection $selectionModel
     * @param \Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\LinkInterface $productLink
     * @param string $linkedProductId
     * @param string $parentProductId
     * @return \Magento\Bundle\Model\Selection
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    protected function mapProductLinkToSelectionModel(
        \Magento\Bundle\Model\Selection $selectionModel,
        \Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\LinkInterface $productLink,
        $linkedProductId,
        $parentProductId
    ) {

        $selectionModel = parent::mapProductLinkToSelectionModel($selectionModel, $productLink, $linkedProductId, $parentProductId);
        if ($productLink->getCustomField() !== null) {
            $selectionModel->setCustomField($productLink->getCustomField());
        }

        return $selectionModel;
    }

    // ....
}
```

And don't forget to add `custom_field` field to DB table `{prefix}_catalog_product_bundle_selection`.
Best way is via `app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php`

**Notice**
I've used preference way for LinkManagement class override for deeper modification of bundle save process. For a question mentioned use case there would be better the plugin way.

Comment: We cannot use plugin for "mapProductLinkToSelectionModel"  since it's a "protected" method. So the solution would be adding "preference" I believe.

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.

getting above error

Comment: @Vitaliy Mashchenko It work great for me thanks buddy.

Comment: @Vitaliy Data is not saved in to the field

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You rocked @Vitaliy

Comment: Thanks it's working fine for me.... @Vitaliy Mashchenko

Comment: Awesome Thank you..

Comment: Thanks Its working for me. but the custom field is not coming while exporting the csv file. I want to add that value while uploading the csv.