# Magento 2 Add Custom fields to Bundle Product add options

Tags: magento2, custom-options, bundled-product, custom-field

want to do this

[image]

I have followed similar ([Magento 2 add new custom option text field](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155132/magento-2-add-new-custom-option-text-field)) topic but it's about custom options for simple products. Somebody in commets say's that he achieved this for bundle following this link. But It didn't work for me.

Here I what i have:

**di.xml** file in my module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<plugin name="bachus_bundlecontextpros_custom_option" type="Bachus\BundleContextPros\Plugin\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundleCustomOptions" sortOrder="1"/>
</type> 
</config>
```

and my **BundleCustomOptions** class

namespace Bachus\BundleContextPros\Plugin\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

class BundleCustomOptions
{

```
public function afterModifyMeta(
    \Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundleCustomOptions $subject,
    $meta
    ) {
        $meta['custom_options']['children']['options']['children']['record']['children']['container_option']['children']['container_common']['children']['custom_text'] =
        $this->getTitleFieldConfig(
            200,
            [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Custom Text'),
                            'component' => 'Magento_Catalog/component/static-type-input',
                            'valueUpdate' => 'input',
                            'imports' => [
                                'optionId' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.option_id'
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
            );
        return $meta;
}

/**
 * Get config for "Title" fields
 *
 * @param int $sortOrder
 * @param array $options
 * @return array
 */
protected function getTitleFieldConfig($sortOrder, array $options = [])
{
    return array_replace_recursive(
        [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Custom Text'),
                        'componentType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => 'custom_text',
                        'dataType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'validation' => [
                            'required-entry' => false
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        $options
        );
}
```

}

**Update:** Now I am able to view the custom field in bunlde options by modyfing Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel.php

adding just after requierd

```
'bundle_template' => [
               'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'dataType' => Form\Element\DataType\Text::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Form\Element\Input::NAME,
                        'componentType' => Form\Field::NAME,
                        'description' => __('bundle template'),
                        'dataScope' => 'bundle_template',
                        'label' => 'bundle template',
                        'sortOrder' => 40,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

**UPDATE** I am able to save the value in data base but not see in admin

I just simply crated colum with exact name that my new custom field has in table **catalog_product_bundle_option** but it didn't work.

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: This might help someone https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/220754/21432

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a plugin to grab the data you stored in database:

di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite">
    <plugin name="PLUGIN_NAME" type="VENDOR\MODULE\Plugin\Composite" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

Plugin\Composite.php

```
    class Composite
{
    /**
     * @var LocatorInterface
     */
    protected $locator;

    /**
     * @var \VENDOR\MODULE\Model\ResourceModel\LIST\Collection
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * Composite constructor.
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite $subject
     * @param $data
     * @return mixed
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function afterModifyData(\Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite $subject, $data)
    {
        if ($this->locator->getProduct()->getTypeId() !== 'bundle') {
            return $data;
        }

        $productId = $this->locator->getProduct()->getId();

        try {
            if (isset($data[$productId]['bundle_options']['bundle_options']) && is_array($data[$productId]['bundle_options']['bundle_options'])) {

                // Select your data from collectionFactory->toArray()['items']
                foreach ($data[$productId]['bundle_options']['bundle_options'] as $key => $option) {

                    foreach ($selectedData as $opData) {

                        if ($opData['option_id'] == $option['option_id']) {

                            $data[$productId]['bundle_options']['bundle_options'][$key]['FIELD'] = $opData['DATA'];

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Could not load collection data'));
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment, however I appreciate the answer from @Emadello.
I see some placeholder code so this example is incomplete.

For example, I do not know what the contents of $option is, I don't know how to load or retrieve only the options values. The answer assumes that the person implementing this would have a deep understanding of this specific area of functionality, in which case they would likely not need this help.

It would be really helpful if you provided a complete answer - explain how to retrieve the values from the database. The primary goal of the plugin for modifyData is to inject data that is not available using the default method - so the answer proposed leaves out the most critical component, that is how to retrieve the information to inject into the response.

Answer (score 0):

Add custom field like 'Default Quantity'

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/220754/21432

This explains how you can add a new field beside 'Default Quantity' field under bundle options