# Magento 2 Add Custom options to Bundle Product add options

Tags: magento2, admin, bundled-product, bundle

When Admin Create an Bundle Product at that time We have Bundle Options box which generated when we click on Add Options

[image]

I want to Add Custom Field into this bundle options box.

Any Suggestion like from where and how to add custom field.

Comment: please follow the link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155132/magento-2-add-new-custom-option-text-field

Comment: I need for bundle Product Options, This ans is about custom options but still this will help. Thanks @NAGARAJUKASA

Comment: Hello @NAGARAJUKASA, I have the same requirement, and when I have done this for bundle product, I can only manage to save the data, but on product load, the saved value can not be displayed. Have you faced any kind of issue?