# Magento 2: Add New Custom Option as a Text Field

Tags: magento2, product

I would like to add a new custom option text field like **'CSS Class'** in the magento 2.3.5 **'Customizable Options'** section.

Anyone can suggest me please and guide me how to add please refer my screenshot for more information;

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2 add new custom option text field](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155132/magento-2-add-new-custom-option-text-field)

Comment: We already tried this but not working for me