# How to add an attribute under bundle product option pane?

Tags: magento2, bundled-product

I want to add an attribute indicated in the red square, how can I archive this? I checked [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155132/magento-2-add-new-custom-option-text-field) but it doesn't look the same as my requirement.

[image]